# Create New Field QGIS Depending on Another Field Using Case

Tags: sql, case, field, calculator, qgis

I'm looking to create a new field in QGIS that is relying on the data contained in another field.

I'm using the field calculator and the case function, but it seems to be trying to pull my conditional string as a field for some reason!

It looks like this - I'm trying to create a new field depending on the existing LEASE field, where its values are Interested, or Toronto.

```
CASE 
when LEASE Like "Interested" or "Toronto" then "Participating" 
Else "Non-Participating" 
End
```

The error I get is

> Column Interested is not found

Any ideas?

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"ColumnName"`. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'Interested'`.

Comment: `... when LEASE IN ('Interested', 'Toronto') then...`

Comment: Thanks for this - however, when I update this way, it now says 
"cannot convert 'Toronto' to boolean".

Edit: Jarlh's function above fixes this.

Comment: That's why you should do `IN (...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals:

```
CASE 
when LEASE IN ('Interested', 'Toronto') then 'Participating'
Else 'Non-Participating'
End
```

That `OR` part has been replaced with an `IN`, to save some typing. You could also do `when LEASE = 'Interested' OR LEASE = 'Toronto' then`, but `IN` is more convenient.